# Open ImageView with Zoom and Scroll

Tags: android, button, scroll, imageview, zooming

I would like to open an Image, in ImageView, from a button press. I need the image to be zoomable and scrollable. How would I best go about accomplishing this?
Thank you!

The Image can be either PNG or JPG

**Thank you so much!**

Here is my new code, you wouldn't mind skimming through and giving me a solution to all my problems with *TAG*, *ZOOM* , etc... I also know I need to add my image *res* to it

```
    package com.DS;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CheatMathActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        public void onTouch(View v) {
   //Opens Algebra Image 
             public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
                     view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
                     float scale;

                     dumpEvent(event);
                     // Handle touch events here...

                     Matrix matrix;
                    Matrix savedMatrix;
                    PointF start;
                    Object mode;
                    float oldDist;
                    PointF mid;
                    switch (event.getAction() & event.ACTION_MASK) 
                     {
                         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // first finger down only
                                                             savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                                             start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                                                             Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
                                                             mode = DRAG;
                                                             break;

                         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

                         case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted

                                                             mode = NONE;
                                                             Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                                                             break;

                         case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down

                                                             oldDist = spacing(event);
                                                             Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                                                             if (oldDist > 5f) {
                                                                 savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                                                 midPoint(mid, event);
                                                                 mode = ZOOM;
                                                                 Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                                                             }
                                                             break;

                         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                                                             if (mode == DRAG) 
                                                             { 
                                                                 matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                                 matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points
                                                             } 
                                                             else if (mode == ZOOM) 
                                                             { 
                                                                 // pinch zooming
                                                                 float newDist = spacing(event);
                                                                 Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                                                                 if (newDist > 5f) 
                                                                 {
                                                                     matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                                     scale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the
                                                                                                 // matrix...if scale > 1 means
                                                                                                 // zoom in...if scale < 1 means
                                                                                                 // zoom out
                                                                     matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                                                                 }
                                                             }
                                                             break;
                     }

                     view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen

                     return true; // indicate event was handled
                }
                private float spacing(MotionEvent event) 
                {
                    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
                    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
                    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
                }

                /*
                 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
                 * Method: midPoint Parameters: PointF object, MotionEvent Returns: void
                 * Description: calculates the midpoint between the two fingers
                 * ------------------------------------------------------------
                 */

                private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) 
                {
                    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
                    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
                    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
                }

                /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
                private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event); 
                {
                    String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE","POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    int action = event.getAction();
                    int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
                    sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);

                    if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) 
                    {
                        sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
                        sb.append(")");
                    }

                    sb.append("[");
                    for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) 
                    {
                        sb.append("#").append(i);
                        sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
                        sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
                        sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
                        if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                            sb.append(";");
                    }

                    sb.append("]");
                    Log.d("Touch Events ---------", sb.toString()); 

            }   





    }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

});
    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
    //Opens Next Subset Image   
        }
    });

}
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
     view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
     float scale;

     dumpEvent(event);
     // Handle touch events here...

     Matrix matrix;
    Matrix savedMatrix;
    PointF start;
    Object mode;
    float oldDist;
    PointF mid;
    switch (event.getAction() & event.ACTION_MASK) 
     {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // first finger down only
                                             savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                             start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                                             Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
                                             mode = DRAG;
                                             break;

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted

                                             mode = NONE;
                                             Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                                             break;

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down

                                             oldDist = spacing(event);
                                             Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                                             if (oldDist > 5f) {
                                                 savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                                 midPoint(mid, event);
                                                 mode = ZOOM;
                                                 Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                                             }
                                             break;

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                                             if (mode == DRAG) 
                                             { 
                                                 matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                 matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points
                                             } 
                                             else if (mode == ZOOM) 
                                             { 
                                                 // pinch zooming
                                                 float newDist = spacing(event);
                                                 Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                                                 if (newDist > 5f) 
                                                 {
                                                     matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                     scale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the
                                                                                 // matrix...if scale > 1 means
                                                                                 // zoom in...if scale < 1 means
                                                                                 // zoom out
                                                     matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                                                 }
                                             }
                                             break;
     }

     view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen

     return true; // indicate event was handled
}
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) 
{
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Method: midPoint Parameters: PointF object, MotionEvent Returns: void
 * Description: calculates the midpoint between the two fingers
 * ------------------------------------------------------------
 */

private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) 
{
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}

/** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE","POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int action = event.getAction();
    int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);

    if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) 
    {
        sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
        sb.append(")");
    }

    sb.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) 
    {
        sb.append("#").append(i);
        sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
        sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
        sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
        if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
            sb.append(";");
    }

    sb.append("]");
    Log.d("Touch Events ---------", sb.toString()); 

}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add these below methods in your activity.  Also, you need call this method as below and your activity must implement `OnTouchListener`.

`imaveViewInstance.setOnTouchListener(this);`

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
     view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
     float scale;

     dumpEvent(event);
     // Handle touch events here...

     switch (event.getAction() & event.ACTION_MASK) 
     {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // first finger down only
                                             savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                             start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                                             Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
                                             mode = DRAG;
                                             break;

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted

                                             mode = NONE;
                                             Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                                             break;

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down

                                             oldDist = spacing(event);
                                             Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                                             if (oldDist > 5f) {
                                                 savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                                 midPoint(mid, event);
                                                 mode = ZOOM;
                                                 Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                                             }
                                             break;

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                                             if (mode == DRAG) 
                                             { 
                                                 matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                 matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points
                                             } 
                                             else if (mode == ZOOM) 
                                             { 
                                                 // pinch zooming
                                                 float newDist = spacing(event);
                                                 Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                                                 if (newDist > 5f) 
                                                 {
                                                     matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                     scale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the
                                                                                 // matrix...if scale > 1 means
                                                                                 // zoom in...if scale < 1 means
                                                                                 // zoom out
                                                     matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                                                 }
                                             }
                                             break;
     }

     view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen

     return true; // indicate event was handled
}
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) 
{
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Method: midPoint Parameters: PointF object, MotionEvent Returns: void
 * Description: calculates the midpoint between the two fingers
 * ------------------------------------------------------------
 */

private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) 
{
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}

/** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE","POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int action = event.getAction();
    int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);

    if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) 
    {
        sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
        sb.append(")");
    }

    sb.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) 
    {
        sb.append("#").append(i);
        sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
        sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
        sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
        if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
            sb.append(";");
    }

    sb.append("]");
    Log.d("Touch Events ---------", sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 26):

Or use [TouchImageView](http://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView) in place of ImageView.  It's a well done class, I've used it myself - Just include his view wherever you need a zoomable imageview.

Comment: The link is broken, here's the new working link: https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

Comment: Perfect solution! Thanks;)

Comment: That version is no longer under development. However, it has been forked to https://github.com/hannesa2/TouchImageView

Comment: Doesnt work for me, I added as you can say in places where I need zoomable imageViews, and doesnt even show the image, thanks anyway