# How pinch zoom image in image zoom android?

Tags: android, image, zooming, pinch

I have to display image in an imageview. 
And what I want to do is just simply pinch and zoom functionality on imageview.

Comment: Just go for link....you found some solution...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399296/how-to-implement-zoom-effect-for-image-view-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128842/open-imageview-with-zoom-and-scroll

Comment: check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18221207/4251431) its awesome and `one line of code`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can find below a link to a class created by Jason Polites that will allow you to handle pinch zooms on custom ImageViews: https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview.

Just include this package into your application and then you will be able to use a custom `GestureImaveView` in your XML files:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:gesture-image="http://schemas.polites.com/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.polites.android.GestureImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    gesture-image:min-scale="0.1"
    gesture-image:max-scale="10.0"
    gesture-image:strict="false"/>
```

This class handles pinch zooms, but also double taps.

Comment: It really helped me..
Great..

Comment: Try this gesture library it comes with an out-of-the-box pan zoom mode: https://bitbucket.org/warwick/hacergestov3

Answer (score 33):

You can  use Chrisbanes photoview library:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: I have done this just now. I only have the emulator for testing right now. Should click and drag with the mouse move the image? It doesn't. However, when I double-click, it zooms the image.

Comment: It also appears that zooming the image does not resize the image. So a lot of the image gets cropped out when it enlarges (From my double tap testing). Do you know any libraries to resize the image on pinch? I cannot find one. They all say pinch zoom. Not pinch resize/scale. Thanks

Comment: Can i save the zoomed image using this library?

Comment: @user2602079  What is the difference between pinch zoom and pinch resize?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319401/Simple-Gestures-on-Android

try this library it is really amazing it gives pich zoom rotate with the amazing smoothness and is much easy to use