# Android pinch-zoom into image

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am trying to display an image and pinch-zoom into the image. There doesn't seem to be any built in thing for this. I saw that there are some libraries, but would much rather not use a library for this.

Anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: You can use a webview for image make an html of your image and open in webview so you can easily zoomIn and ZoomOut your Image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894215/how-pinch-zoom-image-in-image-zoom-android) which uses this [library](https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview). And also refer the library by [Chrisbanes](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView). This is the best place for beginner [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319401/Simple-Gestures-on-Android)