# Applying Zoom on Imageview and Sliding Imges

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, slideshow

```
 public class ShowImgsActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
    int imagesArray[]={R.drawable.a1,R.drawable.a2,R.drawable.a3};
    private ImageView img;
    private List<String> sd;
    float x1,x2;
    float y1, y2;
    private String[] files;
    private AssetManager assetManager;
    private int possition;
    static int forwarInt=1;


     private static final String TAG = "Touch";
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1f,MAX_ZOOM = 1f;

        // These matrices will be used to scale points of the image
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

        // The 3 states (events) which the user is trying to perform
        static final int NONE = 0;
        static final int DRAG = 1;
        static final int ZOOM = 2;
        int mode = NONE;

        // these PointF objects are used to record the point(s) the user is touching
        PointF start = new PointF();
        PointF mid = new PointF();
        float oldDist = 1f;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.showimgsscreen);
        init();
    }
    private void init() {
        img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_prev);    
          assetManager =ShowImgsActivity.this.getAssets();
           possition=getIntent().getIntExtra("Main_position",0);
           try {
               files = assetManager.list("Deaf/0"+possition);
            getImage(getApplicationContext(), "Deaf/0"+possition, 0);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
           forwarInt=0;
    }
    private void getImage(Context conetx,String folderName,int pos) throws IOException
    {
      if(pos<=files.length-1 && pos>=0)
      {

      Bitmap bmp;
       bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetManager.open(folderName+"/"
              + files[pos]));
       img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
      img.setOnTouchListener(this);
      }else if (pos>files.length-1) {
          forwarInt=files.length-1;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "move backward", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
      else if (pos<0) {
          forwarInt=0;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "move forward", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
      else{
          Log.e("_____________", "less greater");
      }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
//      touch=true;
        switch (touchevent.getAction())
        {
        // when user first touches the screen we get x and y coordinate
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {
            x1 = touchevent.getX();
            y1 = touchevent.getY();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {
            x2 = touchevent.getX();
            y2 = touchevent.getY(); 

            //if left to right sweep event on screen
            if (x1 < x2)
            {
                forwarInt++;

                Toast.makeText(this, "Left to Right Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    getImage(getApplicationContext(), "Deaf/0"+possition, forwarInt);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // if right to left sweep event on screen
            if (x1 > x2)
            {
                forwarInt--;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Right to Left Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    getImage(getApplicationContext(), "Deaf/0"+possition, forwarInt);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // if UP to Down sweep event on screen
            if (y1 < y2)
            {
                //              Toast.makeText(this, "UP to Down Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            //if Down to UP sweep event on screen
            if (y1 > y2)
            {
                //              Toast.makeText(this, "Down to UP Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        }
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        float scale;

   //     dumpEvent(event);
        // Handle touch events here...

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // first finger down only
                                                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                                                Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
                                                mode = DRAG;
                                                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted

                                                mode = NONE;
                                                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                                                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down

                                                oldDist = spacing(event);
                                                Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                                                if (oldDist > 5f) {
                                                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                                    midPoint(mid, event);
                                                    mode = ZOOM;
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                                                }
                                                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                                                if (mode == DRAG) 
                                                { 
                                                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points
                                                } 
                                                else if (mode == ZOOM) 
                                                { 
                                                    // pinch zooming
                                                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                                                    if (newDist > 5f) 
                                                    {
                                                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                        scale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the
                                                                                    // matrix...if scale > 1 means
                                                                                    // zoom in...if scale < 1 means
                                                                                    // zoom out
                                                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                break;
        }

        view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen

        return true; // indicate event was handled
    }

     /*
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Method: spacing Parameters: MotionEvent Returns: float Description:
     * checks the spacing between the two fingers on touch
     * ----------------------------------------------------
     */

    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /*
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Method: midPoint Parameters: PointF object, MotionEvent Returns: void
     * Description: calculates the midpoint between the two fingers
     * ------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
    private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE","POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int action = event.getAction();
        int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);

        if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) 
        {
            sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
            sb.append(")");
        }

        sb.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) 
        {
            sb.append("#").append(i);
            sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
            sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
            sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
            if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                sb.append(";");
        }

        sb.append("]");
        Log.d("Touch Events ---------", sb.toString());
    }
}
```

i have images that are available in assets folder . I have Applied Sliding on Images now i want to apply zooming on each Image. But when i apply zooming functionality then Sliding functionality can't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128842/open-imageview-with-zoom-and-scroll?rq=1 i believe this will help you

Comment: I am confused about Zooming Functionality in Gallery.