# How to put an image on my screen?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I have an image which is equal the screen 3 times, how can I put it in a page? How can I maximize it and minimize it (No arrows, no gallery)

Comment: Have you tried anything (including Google)?

Comment: When I put <ImageView android:src="@drawable/picture" /> it just put it without any movement, when I put android:background="@drawable/picture" it just put there! I want to maximize and minimize ... just one picture!

Comment: this might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128842/open-imageview-with-zoom-and-scroll

Comment: What I want looks exactly like this http://oi61.tinypic.com/2zoiweq.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your trying to accomplish [this](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html). Next time, just do a quick [Google Search](http://goo.gl/tTlsVs) for what your trying to do.
For pinching and zooming go [here](http://goo.gl/HEiqfn).

Comment: Thanks Andrew but I posted something

Comment: Anytime! Hope that helps!