# TouchImageView not working smoothly

Tags: android, xml, imageview, pinchzoom, touchimageview

In the following link ([Open ImageView with Zoom and Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128842/open-imageview-with-zoom-and-scroll/39375849#39375849)), in the comments, the TouchImageView from MikeOrtiz is mentioned as a solution for pinchzoom ImageView (and I have seen it mentioned multiple times on different topics);

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

Yet I tried it several times, but zooming while pinching does not work smoothly. Zooming using double-tap does work smoothly. What could be my problem?

I copied the class into my project and set it in XML. I have set the TouchImageView as a child from ScrollView. The image I have in this TouchImageView is visible, double-tap zooms in and out smoothly, but pinching does not work properly. I don't know where to look for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you , i think your problem about size of view. Change image size example like 100x100.  You can resize with any program easily and try again i hope this helpful for you.

Comment: It's pretty late, I just forgot to respond, I'm sorry about that. I found another library that helped me out pretty easily :). I used this [PhotoViewAttacher](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library that does everything I wanted!